Cosmos DB add multiple subnet IDs
Terraform does not make it easy to loop through subnet IDs.  How can you add multiple subnet ids to the cosmos db azurerm resource virtual_network_rule block?  I'm able to pass each subnet id, but this error shows up for all of them:
Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

data.tf
#VNETs
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vss-np-vnet" {
  provider            = azurerm.nonprod
  name                = var.np_vnet_name
  resource_group_name = var.np_net_rg_name
}


#Subnets
data "azurerm_subnet" "np-subnets" {
  provider = azurerm.nonprod
  count                = length(data.azurerm_virtual_network.vss-np-vnet.subnets)
  name                 = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vss-np-vnet.subnets[count.index]
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vss-np-vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vss-np-vnet.resource_group_name

}

cosmos_db.tf
###############################################################################################
#                                      Cosmos DB                                              #
###############################################################################################
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "np-cosmos-db" {
  provider                              = azurerm.nonprod
  name                                  = var.np_cosmos_db_name
  location                              = var.ea2_location
  resource_group_name                   = var.np_rg1_name
  offer_type                            = "Standard"
  kind                                  = "GlobalDocumentDB"
  is_virtual_network_filter_enabled     = true
  network_acl_bypass_for_azure_services = true
  ip_range_filter                       = "104.42.195.92,40.76.54.131,52.176.6.30,52.169.50.45,52.187.184.26"

  tags = merge(var.base_np_tags, { Componet = "Cosmos DB" })

  capacity {
    total_throughput_limit = 4000
  }

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "Session"
    max_interval_in_seconds = 5
    max_staleness_prefix    = 100
  }

  backup {
    type                = "Periodic"
    interval_in_minutes = 60
    retention_in_hours  = 72
    storage_redundancy  = "Local"
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = var.ea2_location
    failover_priority = 0
  }

  analytical_storage {
    schema_type = "WellDefined"
  }

  dynamic "virtual_network_rule" {
    for_each = data.azurerm_subnet.np-subnets.*.id
    content {
      id   = virtual_network_rule.value.id
      ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true
    }
  }

}

Errors:
.
.
.
 Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on cosmos_db.tf line 46, in resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "np-cosmos-db":
│   46:       id   = virtual_network_rule.value.id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ virtual_network_rule.value is "/subscriptions//resourceGroups/ACE-P-NETWORK-RGP-05/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet_name/subnets/subnet_name"
│
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).


How are you declaring data source data.azurerm_subnet.np-subnets?

Are you still facing the issue. @NickP

Removing the ".id" in id   = virtual_network_rule.value.id in the dynamic network_rules block resolved my issue.


Adding multiple subnet IDs to cosmosDB using terraform

The issue was with the way you refer vnet id dynamically inside  Cosmosdb configuration when we are using these type of configurations we should use map the value that iterate and here referencing the value is the issue.
When I test the sample and came across it the changes you refered to.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "example_cosmosdb" {
  name                                  = "vksb-cosmosdb"
  location                              = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.location
  resource_group_name                   = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.name
  offer_type                            = "Standard"
  kind                                  = "GlobalDocumentDB"
  is_virtual_network_filter_enabled     = true
  network_acl_bypass_for_azure_services = true
  ip_range_filter                       = "104.42.195.92,40.76.54.131,52.176.6.30,52.169.50.45,52.187.184.26"

  tags = {
    Environment = "NonProd"
    Owner       = "Vinay"
    Component   = "Cosmos DB"
  }

  capacity {
    total_throughput_limit = 4000
  }

  consistency_policy {
    consistency_level       = "Session"
    max_interval_in_seconds = 5
    max_staleness_prefix    = 100
  }

  backup {
    type                = "Periodic"
    interval_in_minutes = 60
    retention_in_hours  = 72
    storage_redundancy  = "Local"
  }

  geo_location {
    location          = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.location
    failover_priority = 0
  }

  analytical_storage {
    schema_type = "WellDefined"
  }

  dynamic "virtual_network_rule" {
    for_each = [
      azurerm_subnet.example_subnet1.id,
      azurerm_subnet.example_subnet2.id
    ]
    content {
      id = virtual_network_rule.value
      ignore_missing_vnet_service_endpoint = true
    }
  }
}

Deployment:


Refer:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cosmosdb_account
https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks
blog: https://www.techtarget.com/searchitoperations/tutorial/Simplify-code-with-for_each-and-dynamic-blocks-in-Terraform#:~:text=In%20Terraform%2C%20dynamic%20blocks%20let,in%20a%20map%20or%20list.
